# Unable to use WPA security when using laptop as hotspot with an Intel 3945ABG

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless, wpa

When I use my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 as hotspot, I am only allowed to use WEP security instead of WPA.

I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows on this laptop and when I use Windows to create the hotspot I am allowed to use WPA security so it is not a hardware issue.

- I use Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG wireless connection.

Comment: I've seen this problem on many different hardware configs, starting a bounty.

Comment: I think it would be better to cut "with an Intel 3945ABG" from the title as it's not just this card affected.

Answer (score 1):

I researched for an answer for almost an hour, and was unable to find anything. It appears that the ubuntu built-in hotspot service doesn't support WPA.

(I could be wrong; in fact, I hope I'm wrong. The built-in hotspot service **should** support WPA, and if it doesn't then they should definitely update it.)

At this point I think the only way to create a hotspot with WPA security capabilities would be to use third-party software.

The other option would be to use WEP. It has some serious problems as far as security, but if security isn't a big concern then it could be an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Choose wep 40/128 mode, not Wpa.
Detail info: http://tumutanzi.com/archives/8195

Comment: While this might be a good answer to the question it is important to add the information from the link you supplied in to your answer. Answer that are mostly composed by a link do no belong on the site.

Comment: Also, WEP is [extremely insecure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Flaws) (regardless of the key length or password length/randomness)--if any form of WPA is available, that should almost always be used instead. (If security is not important, unencrypted wireless can be used instead...)